# Can't get has_and_belongs_to_many association to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

This is my first time creating a has_and_belongs_to_many association and it is being less than cooperative.

My models are

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
```

and

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
```

I'm trying to create a service through the server object.

I've gotten the server object by `server = Server.find_by_name(server_name)` which works just fine.  If I try to create a services object, either by `service = server.services.new` or `server.services.create(params)` I get the following ActiveRecord error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasAndBelongsToManyAssociationForeignKeyNeeded: Cannot create self referential has_and_belongs_to_many association on 'Service#services'. :association_foreign_key cannot be the same as the :foreign_key.
```

I haven't found much in the way of information for that error though.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple error:

Should be `has_and_belongs_to_many :servers` in your Service class.

Answer (score 0):

first, i think you have a typo there you meant servers not services

it must be

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :servers
```

there are two ways to setup many-to-many associations ins rails, i would suggest to use has_many :through since has_and_belongs_to_many is very limited.

Ryan created a nice Railscasts on this topic which is very helpful!
http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many